Resolving Unexpected Identifier 'assert' SyntaxError in Node.jswhile Importing JSON with ES Modules
I am encountering a SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'assert' when attempting to import a JSON file using the assert { type: "json" } syntax in a Node.js project. The issue occurs with the following line of code:
import skiTerms from "./ski-terms.json" assert { type: "json" };

The full error message is:
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'assert'
    at compileSourceTextModule (node:internal/modules/esm/utils:338:16)
    at ModuleLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:103:18)
    at #translate (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:437:12)
    at ModuleLoader.loadAndTranslate (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:484:27)
    at async ModuleJob._link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:115:19)

I have already set up my project to use ES modules by adding "type": "module" to my package.json, but the error persists. I am using Node.js v23.2.0.

Try running your file using node --experimental-json-modules yourFile.js  , this will enable any JSON-related config. You can also configure the same in your package.json file in scripts.

Please note that import assertions (ie import ... assert ... syntax) are deprecated and have been replaced by import attributes (ie import ... with ... syntax). See here and here
